# Help on a step in this proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question

Suppose $P \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $P^2 = P$. Prove that $V = \text{null} P \oplus \text{range} P$ where $V$ is a vector space and $\mathcal{L}$ are the set of operators.

I looked a proof for this and they decomposed a $v \in V$ as

$v=Pv+(v-Pv)$

To prove that $v-Pv \in \text{nullP}$

they used the argument:

Since $P^2=P$, $P(v-Pv)=(P-P^2)v=0$ Thus $v-Pv \in \text{nullP}$

I am lost about why this last result implies $v-Pv \in \text{nullP}$

Is $P-P^2=P$?

Can someone help explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\text{nullP}$ is the set of vectors that $P$ sends to $0$.  As they have just shown $P(v-Pv)=0$, then $v-Pv \in \text{nullP}$

Comment: I can see why $P-P^2=0$ why does this imply $(P-P^2)v=0$? Why were they allowed to make $P-P^2$ act on an arbitrary vector in $V$?

Comment: The axioms of a vector space include $0v=0$ for any vector $v$, where the $0$ on the left is an operator and the $0$ on the right is a vector.